# Dynamics 365 when used in Chrome uses different font types and sizes

Tags: google-chrome, dynamics-crm

Please could you guide me if it is possible to change the multiple font types and sizes when D365 is used in Chrome. All linked values appear in different fonts. Is it a browser issue or settings adjustable in the CRM?
Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQy6e.png)

Comment: It's not adjustable in CRM

Comment: Attaching the screenshot. See the link. I am not allowed to embed images.